# PHP weird error with empty() function

Tags: php

I uploaded a project from localhost to remote server and it didn't work. I found out that these lines are causing the error

```
if(!empty(ltrim(rtrim($string)))){
    $default_value = $string;
}
```

Then I have changed it to

```
$string = ltrim(rtrim($string));
if(!empty($string)){
    $default_value = $string;
}
```

And it's working. What is causing the error ?

No error is shown, only blank page.
Changing ltrim(rtrim($string)) to just trim($string) doesn't help.

Comment: 1. *What is causing the error ?* What error? 2. right and left trim combine it to a simple `trim()` call!

Comment: Why do both ltrim() and rtrim() when you can simply do trim() instead?

Comment: @MarkBaker I think because, he thinks that `trim()` also removes whitespace between 2 words.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using though? There were changes made to PHP 5.5.0 that allowed the results of expressions to be passed to empty: prior to that, you had to pass a variable

Comment: @MarkBaker PHP Version 5.4.36-0+deb7u3

Comment: @MarkBaker
thanks guys, the problem is caused by the php version

Note:
Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

Comment: Don't use `empty` to begin with here. Either `if (trim($string))`, or `strlen(trim($string)) > 0`. No use for `empty` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until PHP 5.5 `empty()` only expected variables and from then on it also works with expressions. You must have PHP 5.5+ and your server runs a lower version.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php